# Unable to extract String from df Column

Tags: string, scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I want to add a column to my DF. Content of the new Column is based on other columns. This is what I did:

```
val dfr = DFRejID.withColumn("CAUSE_REJET", lit("Reg_ctrl_axe/pas de correspondance pour " + DFRejID.select("COD_ENTREP").as[String].collect()))
```

This is the result:

```
Reg_ctrl_axe/pas de correspondance pour ID_ENTITE=[Ljava.lang.String;@9d1fe08
```

How can I decode that please. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work!

```
val dfr = DFRejID.withColumn("CAUSE_REJET", concat(lit("Reg_ctrl_axe/pas de correspondance pour "), $"COD_ENTREP"))
```

You do not want to nest a `.select` within your first command. Also, calling `.collect` will create a collection on your master node (not the executors) and you want to avoid that as well.

Comment: Thak you. This worked. Just a quick question: why did you replace **+** with **concat**? Is it only better ?

Comment: I believe that `+` will yield `null`. If that works for you feel free to swap it!